# Scrollpane in multi-panel tab of JTabbedpanes

Tags: java, jtable, scrollpane, pane

Good day all,

I have a JTabbedPane of which each tab has its own class. Each of its ActionListener also has it's own seperated class. 
One ActionPerformed happens to add a JTable with columns after a certain amount of days is set.

This is one tab:

```
public class FirstTab {

private JPanel mainPane;
private JPanel weeksPane;
private JButton setWeeksB;
private JLabel matchCheck;
private JPanel modulesPane;

public FirstTab() {

    mainPane = new JPanel();
    weeksPane = new JPanel();
    setWeeksB = new JButton("Voeg weken toe");
    matchCheck = new JLabel(); 
    //mainPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    mainPane.add(createSchoolDaysPane());
}


public JPanel createSchoolDaysPane() {

    JPanel schoolDaysPane = new JPanel(); 

    DefaultTableModel weeksModelTable = new DefaultTableModel(); 
    weeksModelTable.addColumn("Week nummer");
    weeksModelTable.addColumn("Dagen");
    JTable weeksTable = new JTable(weeksModelTable);
    JLabel schoolDaysL = new JLabel("Geef hier het aantal schooldagen (max 200) van het jaar in: ");
    JTextField schoolDaysF = new JTextField(10);
        SetWeeksPaneAction AWFA = new SetWeeksPaneAction(mainPane, weeksPane, weeksModelTable, weeksTable, matchCheck, setWeeksB);
        schoolDaysF.addActionListener(AWFA);
    JLabel schoolDaysGivenL = new JLabel();
    schoolDaysPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(schoolDaysPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    schoolDaysPane.add(schoolDaysL);
    schoolDaysPane.add(schoolDaysF);   
    schoolDaysPane.add(schoolDaysGivenL);

    return schoolDaysPane;
}


public JPanel getTab() { 

    return mainPane; 
}
```

This tab contains two panels, the JTable shown is added to the panel after the amount of days is set.

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LNaW.png)

As you notice the columns are not visible (but they are set), so I have been told to use a ScrollPane instead.

However, I am not able to pass through a ScrollPane in my JTabbed because a normal pane ('MainPane' - container) is passed through:

```
public EindopdrachtJava3() { 

    frame = new JFrame();
    jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    firstTab = new FirstTab();                      
    secondTab = new SecondTab();                  

    jtp.addTab("Modules", firstTab.getTab());
    jtp.addTab("Samenvatting schooljaar", secondTab.getTab());

    frame.getContentPane().add(jtp);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(640, 480);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    modules = new HashSet<Module>();
    weeks = new HashSet<Week>();

}        

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new EindopdrachtJava3();
}
```

This tab contains multiple panels and gets added to my JFrame in the Main class

```
JFrame {    
   JTabbedPane {
      Tab 1 { 
         Panel 1
         ScrollPane(JTabel)   - But not possible(?)
      }
      Tab 2 { 
         ....
      }
}
```

I would like to keep it modular as possible since that is currently my learning curve in GUI

Comment: Why not use the JScrollPane inside each of the tabbed pane classes? I have to wonder how different each of these classes are, and if there's a lot of redundancy going on.

Comment: A JScrollpane is one pane, while my tabs have more panels. Is using a ScrollPane as container for both panels not wrong?

Referring to your redundancy I do not exactly know what you mean: I want to use full modularity (I have read an article about this linked here on Stack) so I need to pass Components through ActionListeners.

Comment: You're thinking to literal about your problem.  You shouldn't need to pass UI elements to other components in this case, instead, pass the data you want those components to display and allow them to construct the UI that they need to do so ... basically what Hovercraft said

Comment: I am entirely lost now: if I do not pass UI elements through the constructors of the ActionListener classes, it would mean that class needs to create them, thus a user can create infinite amount of UI elements by just clicking as many times the user wants. How else should I prevent that: using buttonIsPressed = true? Another article said that would be wrong..

Comment: Or HoverCraft are you referring to how much a JPanel is different from a JScrollPanel while talking about redundancy?